# Which modules are required to make yellowpage in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am learning Drupal. I want to create a yellowpage in Drupal 7.

The site will have following main features :

1. Different business Category
2. Registered User will create business linting. Each business category will have different form fields for creating business listing.
3. Rating on business listing.
4. Map of business listing.
5. Third party Ads on a Page.
6. Search based on business category,location,keyword,business name etc .
7. Share to social websites like FB, Twitter.
8. Email to friend.

Which modules do I require to make a yellowpage?

Answer (score 1):

You will need the following modules in addition to core taxonomy module to create your content types.

> Different business Category
>   Registered user will create business listing. Each business category
>   will have different

Taxonomy

> form fields for creating business listing.

Drupal's core field modules will allow you to build out your business content type.

> Rating on business listing.

[VotingAPI](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi)
Provides base voting architecture, required by fivestar.

[Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar)
Provides rating widgets for nodes.

> Map of business listing.

[Location](https://drupal.org/project/location)
Allows you to attach a location to a node.

[Gmap](https://drupal.org/project/gmap)
Allows you to make google maps with Drupal Views, and attach maps to nodes.

> Third party Ads on a Page.

Not enough info. You could use standard nodes, or a standard block with google ads or some other ad provider's code inside of it.

> Search based on business category, location, keyword, business name etc .

You could achieve this with [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) or you may want to look into [Solr search](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) and Solr views.

> Share to social websites like FB, Twitter.

[Share This](http://drupal.org/project/sharethis)

> Email to friend.

[Print](http://drupal.org/project/print)